# My extension shows up in Chrome, how can I stop this?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I am learning how to make chrome extensions. What I am trying to do is only useful at one specific website, so I hoped that I can somehow "hide" the extension when I am not at this website. It seems like Chrome Remote Desktop or Google docs extensions also don't show up next to the adress bar. How can I achieve the same with my extension? Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description" : "I am learning",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can move/hide the icon manually by rightclicking it. Chrome always shows all extensions either next to the address bar or inside the menu.

Comment: So google docs is just an exception because it was created by google? Hm I guess I will just add functionality to the icon then if it has to be there.

Comment: Google Docs might be a Chrome Applications, Not a Chrome Extension.